# Setting of one image in carousel without any movement

Tags: materialize

I need to add only one image to the carousel through materialize css, but that image should stay in its position without moving when clicked on the space around the image.

```
<div class="carousel" >
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a> 
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

I am able to display one image in the carousel but the image is hiding when clicked on the space around the image.

Comment: i think you just add `singleItem: true`

Comment: Sorry,its not working out.